# How to combine two enviroment variables into one command?

Tags: environment-variables

I have an old pc and I installed Ubuntu 13. 10 on it.
I also installed skype and the issue is that I have a huge audio latency or my webcam not work.

I have work by replace 'Exec=skype' with:

- Audio fix: `Exec=env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 skype %U`
- Webcam fix: `Exec=bash -c 'LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype'`

On `sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop`.

I used 1 or other and not both.

I want to know if I can do something like:

```
Exec=bash -c 'LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype' && env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 skype %U`
```

Does the '&&' command make bash and env command to run simultaneously or is a better way on how to write it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to combine your two solutions:

`Exec=bash -c 'export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so && env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 skype %U'`

Comment: Care to explain what this do?

Comment: I've updated it.

Comment: Thanks for all, also for Braiam editing :) .. I have to say I'm not an IT guy ( I study chemistry ), talked with a friend and he told me to use ' \n ' and not ' && ' and I have to say it work batter with ' \n ' but I still have an audio lag of 1-2 sec when the webcam is on. Any type I could use to get it better?

Comment: I don't think there's much room for improvement. It sounds more like a network related issue, webcam on means more data to transfer, which results in higher latency. 1-2 seconds is within the normal range, unfortunately. How fast is your internet connection (http://speedtest.net)?